# Which layer should my JBehave acceptance test target in a DDD application?

Tags: unit-testing, architecture, domain-driven-design, acceptance-testing

Given a DDD application with a hexagonal architecture, which layer should my JBehave acceptance tests target?

I want to write Features and scenarios as specifications for the overall system behavior as we are introducing **ATDD** as our development process.

In my application I have these layers:

- Presentation layer
- Web services layer
- Application services layer
- Domain layer
- Infrastructure layer

Comment: this might belong on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Generally JBehave is seen as [unit testing framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#Java) for [Behavior-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development), which I think will combine well with your current design

> we are introducing ATDD as our development process

So as *bottom line* -  it's strongly recommended to have unit tests for all app levels, but I think that especially in the case of JBehave, it will be helpful if you use it not only in your *Presentation*, but also in Application services and Domain layers too.